Unable to understand the difference between normal comparison of strings and comparison using localCompare() method as both works differently
`I am a newbie in JavaScript and to programming. Need assistance to clarify this doubt
console.log('a'>'A'); This code returns True

let result = 'a'.localeCompare('A'); 
console.log(result); 
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale);

This code returns -1 and my locale is en-IN

This is creating a confusion because, if 'a'>'A' then localeCompare() should return 1 instead it is returning -1
Checked for the working of localeCompare() method and it runs on some Unicode collation algorithm so unable to follow up with it.`

"unable to follow up with it" -- why not?

If you are asking, whether comparison < or > are the same as .localCompare, then the answer is no.

@ASDFGerte He's not asking about .localCompare, he's asking about localeCompare

@ControlAltDel typo indeed, but edit timer ran out now :)

Whether Unicode Collation Algorithm considers lowercase letters to be less than uppercase letters in a case-sensitive comparison?

The order of different cases the same letter in localeCompare depends on the  locale, so you can't rely on it being the same as 'a'>'A' everywhere.
If you want to ensure the order of these are consistent, regardless of locale, you can use the caseFirst setting.
For example:
'a'.localeCompare('A', 'en-IN', {caseFirst:'upper'}); 

will return a positive number, which sounds like it's what your expecting.
Alternatively, you can use the sensitivity setting if you'd like to ignore case altogether
'a'.localeCompare('A', 'en-IN', {sensitivity:'base'}); 

will return a zero.
